# Group project via Team Foundation 2010

Tags: tfs

We will be doing a database driven logistics system for our Software Analysis and Design course. What we want to do is to work on the project simultaneously so that we can finish the project earlier. Is TFS the right tool for this? If yes, how do we start? What are the steps to set up the TFS? We use VS 2010.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question. TFS is an excellent code repository that does allow for multiple developers to have a centralised code base (which sounds like what you are after).
The first thing you will need of course is the TFS 2010 installation disk and ideally a separate box to install it on. Although the installation and set up can differ slightly on differing OS, i would recommend following the installation guide [here](http://juliocasal.com/archive/2009/10/23/installing-team-foundation-server-2010-beta-2-on-windows-7-using-the-basic-configuration.aspx) and posting any specific and more detailed questions as you come across issues.

Answer (score 0):

Is TFS the right tool for this:  Maybe.  It may be a bit much overhead to use for a course.

How do you start:  If you have Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, TFS should be included.  Everything is installation wizard based, and the install (can) give you everything you need.  For what you want, a stand-alone installation using SQL Server Express should be fine.

If you're looking for something lightweight that you all could use for source control, you might want to consider some of the git/svn hosting services (e.g. http://unfuddle.com).  There's no direct integration with Visual Studio without a third-party tool, but it will give you the basics of being able to share source code among your team.